# Determinantal/Fitting ideal of the direct sum of linear maps

Tags: matrices, commutative-algebra, modules, determinant, exterior-algebra

> 5.6. Fact. If G and H are matrices such that GH is defined, then for all n≥0, we have $D_n(GH)⊆D_n(G)D_n(H)$
> Proof: By considering exterior powers, we reduce to the *n=1* case, for which it is clear.
> The following equality is immediate $D_n(\varphi ⊕ \psi)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}D_k(\varphi)D_{n-k}(\psi)$

In the above, $D_n$ is a determinantal ideal and $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are linear maps over free modules of finite rank.
I feel like I'm being silly, but I can't see how it is immediate. Any help would be appreciated.
To be clear, I'm asking how the last equation follows from just the theorem and other elementary facts about determinantal ideals. I would also be happy to see other **constructive** proofs of this equation.

In particular I imagine that we should have to use the elementary fact that if you have a block matrix $G$ with one block the identity of size *r* and the other block the matrix $H$,  then $D_{k+r}(G)=D_k(H)$ for every r≥0
Since the direct sum of matrices can be decomposed into the product of two such matrices, I think this will be used to deduce the result, but I cannot see how.

Comment: Care to spell out what are $\phi,\psi$?

Comment: Linear maps, I will specify in the post

Comment: Linear maps from where to where?

Comment: Free modules of finite rank

Comment: Isn't this just the fact that $\wedge^n(\phi\oplus\psi)=\oplus(\wedge^k(\phi)\otimes\wedge^{n-k}(\psi))$?

Comment: The very same, but I don't see how it immediately follows from this result they prove. (And I haven't seen any other proofs of that to work off).

Comment: I'm not sure actually, they're definitely related but since these are sums of ideals I don't know if it's immediate. Hopefully it will be clear in the answer to this question